# Setting a dictionary key dynamically inside a SelectToList

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically create a dictionary which has an unknown number of keys.

```
model = new RecruiterMetricsViewModel() {
RecruiterMetrics = recMetrics,
    TableData = recMetrics.SelectToListOrEmpty(r => {
        return new TableRowViewModel {
            Id = r.Recruit.Id,
                Class = "",
                Data = new Dictionary < string, string > {
                    {
                        "Name", r.Recruit.FirstName + r.Recruit.LastName
                    },
      /* Here i would like to start a foreach if i could. Making the key 
         equal to an item in my object. And making the value a different 
         item in my object */
                },
        };
    })
};
```

Model:

```
public class RecruiterMetricsViewModel : ListPageViewModel
    {
        public List<RecruiterMetricsModel> RecruiterMetrics { get; set; } 
    }

    public class RecruiterMetricsModel
    {
        public RecruiterRecruitingPerformance Recruit { get; set; }

        public RecruitingPerformance DailyMetrics { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to make the key equal to `DailMetrics.Date` and the value equal to `DailMetrics.Average`.

Comment: A dictionary really doesn't make sense here since you only have a single instance of `RecruiterMetricsModel`. Are you trying to get a single dictionary for all of the items in `recMetrics`? Also...where does `SelectToListOrEmpty` come from?

Comment: The dictionary is from the ListPageViewModel. I don't want to change it I want to keep the dictionary

Comment: I just don't understand what collection you want to "for each" over to create the dictionary. You need a collection to iterate over and you only have an object there. Your dictionary will only ever have a single item which makes no sense.

Comment: The key will be used in a JS array as the column name the value will be used as the actual value. It is how it is setup. I just want to know how to do what i asked.

Comment: You're missing the point. I'm asking questions because it's not at all clear what you were asking originally. Nobody can help you if we can't understand what the problem is.